# Using arrays for updates in visual basic

Tags: arrays, vba

this is my existing code:

```
DBConn.BeginTrans
                    strSQL = "DELETE tblAvailable WHERE "
        strSQL = strSQL + "(intResortID = " + Session("TypeID") + ")"
        strSQL = strSQL + " AND (dtm BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'" + cstr(Year(dtmStart)) + "-" + cstr(Month(dtmStart)) + "-" + cstr(Day(dtmStart)) + "', 102)"
        strSQL = strSQL + " AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'" + cstr(Year(dtmEnd)) + "-" + cstr(Month(dtmEnd)) + "-" + cstr(Day(dtmEnd)) + "', 102))"


        'SY SINGH
        'Add code to only delete out room types contained in the spreadsheet
        Dim i
        strSQL = strSQL & "AND (strRoomType='" & strRooms(0) & "'"
        For i = 1 to m_Rooms
            strSQL = strSQL & " OR strRoomType='" & strRooms(i) & "'"
        next
        strSQL = strSQL & ")"
```

I want to change it to do an update instead, setting curprice where strRoomType is equal to the array of rooms.

this is what I have come up with so far

```
    strSQL = "Update tblAvailable set curprice ="+ FixNumber(curprice (intCurrentData))
    response.Write(strSQL)
    strSQL = strSQL +"WHERE intResortID = " + Session("TypeID")  
    response.Write(strSQL)
    strSQL = strSQL + " AND dtm BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME,'" + cstr(Year(dtmStart)) + "-" + cstr(Month(dtmStart)) + "-" + cstr(Day(dtmStart)) + "', 102)"
    response.Write(strSQL)
    strSQL = strSQL + " AND CONVERT(DATETIME,'" + cstr(Year(dtmEnd)) + "-" + cstr(Month(dtmEnd)) + "-" + cstr(Day(dtmEnd)) + "', 102)"
    response.Write(strSQL)
    dim i 

    strSQL = strSQL + " AND (strRoomType='" & strRooms(0) & "'"
    response.Write(strSQL)
    For i = 1 to m_Rooms
    strSQL = strSQL & " OR strRoomType='" & strRooms(i) & "'"
    response.Write(strSQL)
    next
    strSQL = strSQL & ")"
    response.Write(strSQL)

    DBConn.Execute strSQL
```

this is the error I am receiving:

```
dtm'dtm' OR strRoomType='obeqvb'dtm' OR strRoomType='obeqvb') 
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14' 

Incorrect syntax near 'obeqvb'. 

/upload_excel_v3.asp, line 230
```

obeqvb is my strroomtype and dtm is my date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should escape any single-quotes in your values by doubling them up

`'my'roomtype` should be `'my''roomtype'`

And you're better off using `where strRoomType in(...)` instead of "or"

Comment: By doing this I was able to find the actual bug was in the excel sheet that was uploading to the asp page. Thanks for that!